# MariaDB ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE autoincrement

Tags: mysql, mariadb, innodb

Recently i saw in my database (InnoDB), that my "ID" column which is set to autoincrement, does count a bit weird. When i update a record with

```
INSERT INTO users (user, group) VALUES ('username', 'group') ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE username = 'username', group = 'group'
```

autoincrement counts the ID, so now my table is looking as follows:

```
----------------
|id|user |group|
----------------
|1 |test |3    |
|2 |test2|5    |
|5 |foo  |2    |
|6 |bar  |4    |
|10|user |2    |
----------------
```

I read about this "issue" but didn't really found and answer on how to make the autoincrement field not count, if the record gets updated only.

Comment: Whether or not the auto increment number changes is not really a concern.  The contract only says it has to be unique and ever increasing, not that it will always be continuous.

Comment: So this is not a problem, when the id is getting very high (e.g. one Billion or so)? And there is no way to get arount this?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen - I will dispute the "ever increasing", especially when viewed from a Slave.

Comment: @RickJames I spend 4-6 hours on this site every day, so I'm inclined to call myself the slave.  Yes, you're probably right, and it may not always increase.

Comment: (I added tag [mysql] because this discussion applies identically to both MariaDB and MySQL.)

Comment: `id` has the column type you've assigned it (int, mediumint, bigint...) and integer numbers either fit or not fit. Values within the acceptable range do not become "very high" until they eventually overflow (thus no longer fit).

Comment: Yes that's what i mean, isn't it some sort of waste that there are perhaps many "unused" ids?

Comment: An unsigned `int` overflows after 4,294,967,295. An unsigned `bigint`, after 2^64-1 (18,446,744,073,709,551,615). You'll have bigger problems before you run out of numbers.

Comment: Ok i see, but is this the normal approach for handling auto increment ids? Or does this with another table type differ? I only want the optimal solution for that :)

Answer (score 1):

`INSERT IGNORE`, `REPLACE`, IODKU (that you are using), and some other commands will *first* allocate new id(s), *then* either use them or 'burn' them.  Live with it.

In Multi-master and Clustering environments, `auto_increment_increment` is set to more than 1 so that the nodes can easily avoid each other.  This can lead to lots of gaps.

Since ids are not visible outside the transaction until the `COMMIT`, other queries can see id=7 before id=6 is visible.  The wreaks havoc with some simplistic designs for queuing.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. What is About sending a ALTER TABLE my_table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1 after every IODKU query? That does work, but does it have any drawbacks?

Comment: @andy - You can't start over without throwing out all the ids.  That is, you can't set it to 1 or anything else less than MAX(id)+1.  If you must avoid burning ids, you must test before inserting.

Comment: I understand, but why does the approach work then? What do you exaclty mean by test before inserting?

Comment: @andy - If record does not exist, then insert.

Comment: When using MyISAM format instead of INNODB, it does not create these gaps, so does it have any drawbacks when using that DB format?

Comment: @andy: I never use MyISAM. See my answer to [MyISAM vs. InnoDB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20148/myisam-versus-innodb/17706717#17706717).

Comment: @Bill Karwin - Thank you for that post, really good explanation. So i will stick with InnoDB. But i found the mysql setting "innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0", which does help to avoid unused ids on my table. I read the documentation, which says that "innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=0" does avoid the auto_increment gaps. So is it save to use?

Comment: I think you need to get over worrying about gaps. If you rollback transactions or delete rows, you'll just get gaps for those reasons. Auto-inc primary keys are not meant to be consecutive, just unique.

Comment: So then you suggest that i just leave the default innodb_autoinc_lock_mode=1 and use InnoDB as my table format? The point is, in one table i have not that much new inserts, but a huge amount of updates, everything is inserted / updated with IODKU.

Comment: @andy - If you know that the row exists, use `UPDATE`, not IODKU.

Comment: @Rick James - I don't know, if a row does exist, but it mostly exists. When using UPDATE does it also count the auto_inc? Or is it simply faster than IODKU?

Comment: Ok i tested that and when using UPDATE only, the auto_inc does not count. So is it save to use the following logic?

1. Send UPDATE query
2. If affected_rows > 0 - updated successfully
3. Else Send SELECT query - if num_rows === 0
4. Send INSERT query - if affected_rows > 0 - inserted successfully
5. Else - Nothing changed

Comment: @andy - Less complex:  `SELECT`, then either `UPDATE` or `INSERT`.

Comment: #Rick James - Yes that would be easier, but as i said, most of the querys will be updates, that's why i do an update query first (i know that every update does change the timestamp inside my row). If there is no row to update (no clientid that matches), i do a select to be sure, that there is really no clientid that Matches. And then insert. The problem is, that when (for whatever reason) the update values are equal, i have to re-check.

Answer (score 1):

I take from your comments that you may be concerned about running out of integers if you don't fill every gap in an auto-increment primary key.

I encourage you to do the math. An `INT` is 4 bytes, and holds values up to 2^31-1 (or 2^32-1 for `UNSIGNED INT`). If you were to generate 1 auto-inc id every second (whether it results in an INSERT or else it's discarded), that would last 136 years.

If you're still concerned, then use an `UNSIGNED BIGINT` which has 2^64-1 distinct values. That data type would let you consume 1000 id's per second for 584,542,046 years.